# query a datatable

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I am trying to query a data table to retrieve the data from a data-table based on a input string an eangle can bee seen below

Data-table dat

```
      a  || e || i || o || u || j||
----------------------------------------
value[10]|| 1 || 1 || 1 || 1 || 1  1
string[1]|| 1 || 1 || 1 || 1 || 1  1
value[10]|| 1 || 1 || 1 || 1 || 1  1
value[10]|| 1 || 1 || 1 || 1 || 1  1
value[10]|| 1 || 1 || 1 || 1 || 1  1

input string 

value


output data 
value[10]|| 1 || 1 || 1 || 1 || 1  1
value[10]|| 1 || 1 || 1 || 1 || 1  1
value[10]|| 1 || 1 || 1 || 1 || 1  1
value[10]|| 1 || 1 || 1 || 1 || 1  1
```

the column name can change but the rows do not

all that needs to be matched with the query text is everything before the square brackets that open.

i would like to know how i could do this query becuase the method i have used so far does not work.

```
var result = excelDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where((((row,index)=> index==0)));
```

AND

```
var result = excelDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(data => data.Field<String>(0).StartsWith(queryString));
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to select those rows, whose first column doesn't contain `"string"` in the content. Try the following .

```
var result = excelDataTable.AsEnumerable()
                         .Where(r=> !r.Field<string>(0).StartsWith("string"));
                                    ^^^
                                   //Notice the ! - Not
```

Comment: @user1776590, your query is returning only those which starts with "string". Its not excluding those. You need to put `!` (not) in the where condition

Comment: but that is what i would like to do is only return the ones that start with is string

Comment: @user1776590 your output is contradictory then , and are you sure your first column contains the value ?

Comment: @user1776590, instead of StartsWith try Contains, but seriously it is pointless unless there are white spaces in the start of the string.

Comment: that wont work because that would find any row that conatins that not startw with as the square brackets may have the query text so i need only the data before the start of the square bracket to match

Comment: @user1776590, its not the row being checked against the StartsWith, its the column value

Comment: yes that is the case but within the column with the square brackets the word may appear so in that case that one should be left out